# Test Socket Connectivity between 2 Remote Servers

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sockets, remote-server

I have developed a C# WPF Monitoring application that checks, among other things, connectivity to another server. On the remote server, we have an application service running on a certain port. If we simply telnet to that server's port, we see the service name running.
I am busy transforming my proof-of-concept app into the WPF app so that it constantly checks this connectivity and service running on the remote server using end points and Socket.BeginConnect etc. which works 100%.
However, I would like to monitor several servers each checking connectivity to other remote servers -so I would like a way to be able to run the test from one remote server to another and get the results locally on my WPF app.
One way around this problem would be to run an app on the remote server gathering this information, then getting access to that data, but I would like to get away with that if possible.

Here's my code - very raw, very proof-of-concept at the moment.
I'd like to run this app on my laptop on the network, for example, and monitor other servers:

```
// CPU Usage ----------------------------------------------------------
private string getUsageCPU()
{
    cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();

    cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
    cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
    cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

    return cpuCounter.NextValue() + "%";
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

// Memory Usage -------------------------------------------------------
private string getUsageRAM()
{
    ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
    return ramCounter.NextValue() + " MB";
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

// Service Status -----------------------------------------------------
private string getServicesStatus(string service)
{
    string status = "";
    ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(service);
    try
    {
        status = sc.Status.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        status = "not found: " + ex.Message;
    }
    return status;
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

// Connectivity Test --------------------------------------------------
private string getTelnetResponse(string host, int port)
{
    string result = "";
    IPAddress ipAddress = null;

    try {
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(host);
        if (!IPAddress.TryParse(host, out ipAddress))
        {
            ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        }
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

        // Need to run this from the Server we are monitoring not from where the application is running.
        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Connect to the remote endpoint.
        client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
        connectDone.WaitOne();

        // Send test data to the remote device.
        Send(client, "This is a test<EOF>");
        sendDone.WaitOne();

        // Receive the response from the remote device.
        Receive(client);
        receiveDone.WaitOne();

        // Write the response to the console.
        result = String.Format("Response received : {0}", response);

        // Release the socket.
        client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        client.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        labelValueTelnet.Text = (e.ToString());
    }

    return result;
}

// ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.
private static ManualResetEvent connectDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
private static ManualResetEvent sendDone    = new ManualResetEvent(false);
private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
// The response from the remote device.
private static String response = String.Empty;

// State object for receiving data from remote device.
public class StateObject
{
    // Client socket.
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.
    public const int BufferSize = 256;
    // Receive buffer.
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
        Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete the connection.
        client.EndConnect(ar);

        ////labelValueTelnet.Text = String.Format("Socket connected to {0}", client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

        // Signal that the connection has been made.
        connectDone.Set();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //labelValueTelnet.Text = (e.ToString());
    }
}

private void Receive(Socket client)
{
    try
    {
        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = client;

        // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
        client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        labelValueTelnet.Text = (e.ToString());
    }
}

private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket client = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the remote device.
        int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

            // Get the rest of the data.
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        else
       {
           // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
           if (state.sb.Length > 1)
           {
               response = state.sb.ToString();
            }
            // Signal that all bytes have been received.
            receiveDone.Set();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        labelValueTelnet.Text = (e.ToString());
    }
}

private void Send(Socket client, String data)
{
    // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
    byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

    // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
    client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
}

private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
        Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
        int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
        //labelValueTelnet.Text = String.Format("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);

        // Signal that all bytes have been sent.
        sendDone.Set();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        labelValueTelnet.Text = (e.ToString());
    }
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: How about a little hosted WCF Service, that all your application in all those servers connects and updates data to/from ???

Comment: Thank you MrClan - I am new to C# and .Net and this is my very first application
Would I create a WCF service on each remote server I am monitoring. The WCF service checking connectivity, resources, etc.Each service would update data in a central DB for instance from where my WPF app would read from?

Comment: Something like that. You'll create a **single service** and host it on your main machine which all other remote machines can connect to. And then add the client code in your wpf app(which will be run on all the monitored machines), and will call methods exposed by your WCF service to update their system status. The service will then write that data to a db or log file. To read, you'll again call a method from hosted service.